# Reduce Map object into ArrayList

Tags: java, mapreduce, hashmap, java-stream

I have a distributed system of 4 workers and each are sending 1 **Map< String, MyClass >** object to the reducer in order to reduce them to an **ArrayList< MyClass >**

The way I'm trying to approach it is by collecting all Map items from the workers into an  ArrayList and then using parallel stream I want to use the reduce method to reduce them into a list that I have initialize into the reducer. Here is my code:

```
    ArrayList<MyClass> result = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    maps.parallelStream().reduce(null, (res, m)->{
        result.add(m.get(key));
    });
```

I get the following compilation error on the reduce method:

> The method reduce(Map< String,Directions>, BinaryOperator< Map< String,Directions>>) in the type Stream< Map< String,Directions > > is not applicable for the arguments (null, (< no type > res, < no type > m) -> {})

Comment: No need for the parallel stream. Use the [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) method on the list to add all values from the maps which you get using [values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--).

Comment: There is no `java.util.Map#parallelStream`... But maybe you can use this: `List<Object> objects = maps.values().parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Maybe use `new ArrayList<>(maps.values());`

Comment: Instead of null you need a 'zero' value, for your case that would an empty list. It's the first value that is reduced with.

Comment: @JureKolenko @StefanWarminski I can't take maps.values() because maps is an `ArrayList< Map< String,MyClass>>` not a Map object

Comment: @PaulVlasin I know that but my problem is that I should initialize res there but I was tryin to put something like `new ArrayList<Map<String,MyClass>>(),(res,m)->..` but it didn't work out

Comment: Assuming `list` is your list of maps, try the following: 
  `List<MyClass> result = list.stream().flatMap(v -> v.values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @JureKolenko It worked.thank you.You can put it as an answer so that I can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `list` is your list of maps, try the following:

```
List<MyClass> result = list.stream()
    .flatMap(v -> v.values().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```